# HTC 8x cannot download apps

Tags: 8.0, apps

When I try do download apps on this phone it tells me to change settings in "my family". When I go to "my family" on windowsphone.com I get a "internal server error". I've tried different windows live accounts and tried Zune and get the same message. How can I enable the phone to download apps?

Comment: For the internal server error, I recently had a similar problem with Firefox but it worked with Chrome. Perhaps you could try switch browser and see if that helps?

Comment: oh sure, iPhone will offer you so much more :))

Comment: There are issues if the date of birth on the live id makes you less than 18 years old - have you checked the date of birth is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://live.xbox.com/en-US/Account/Settings and log in there. If it asks you to log in with your parental id, then your account was set up as a child and you need to find the parent account that set it up originally to allow app downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Change your date of birth to over 18 on your Microsoft account it worked for me

Comment: Are you able to flesh out the details a bit more? E.g. a URL and some steps to get to the correct page.